# PHP array grouping values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below

```
array(0=>A,1=>A,2=>B,3=>B,4=>C,5=>A,6=>A)
```

My problem is i need to group the same value with multiple occurrence. For example for the above question I need an array like array('A' => (count1=>2,count2=>2), 'B' => (count1=>2), 'C' => (count1=>1)). How can i loop the array

Comment: What does it mean `count1`, `count2`?

Comment: just a key. For the above question I just need an array like Array(2,2,1,2). The count of occurrence of A,B,C and again A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array(0=>A,1=>A,2=>B,3=>B,4=>C,5=>A,6=>A);

$counters = array();
$prev = NULL;
array_walk(
    $data,
    function ($entry) use (&$prev, &$counters) {
        if ($entry !== $prev) {
            $prev = $entry;
            $counters[] = 1;
        } else {
            $counters[count($counters)-1]++;
        }
    }
);
var_dump($counters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the frequency of values in the array, there is a php function for that called 
 array_count_values($array).

In case of your example,

$data = array(0=>'A',1=>'A',2=>'B',3=>'B',4=>'C',5=>'A',6=>'A');

print_r(array_count_values($data));

would output

Array
(
    [A] => 4
    [B] => 2
    [C] => 1
)

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer -

```
$arr=array(0=>A,1=>A,2=>B,3=>B,4=>C,5=>A,6=>A);
$count=array();$passedelement=array();$pastelement='';$n=0;$k=0;$presentflag=0;
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){                
if($pastelement==$arr[$i]){$presentflag=1;}                 
if($presentflag==0){
$pastelement=$arr[$i];
$passedelement[$k++]=$arr[$i];
for($j=$i;$j<7;$j++){
if($arr[$i]==$arr[$j]){$count[$n]+=1;}else{break;} 
}
$n++;
}
$presentflag=0;
}
print_r($passedelement);
print_r($count);
```